# TortoiseHg 'No space left on device' error while pushing

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We are using TortoiseHg as our Mercurial client UI. Today we ran into an issue while trying to push from one particular workstation.  It was receiving the following error:

*abort: No space left on device
[command returned code 255 ..........]*

This error occurs while TortoiseHg/Mercurial is bundling files in preparation to pushing to the repository.  I did some testing and noticed that the workstations (C:) drive was gradually being filled up as the file were being bundled.  The (C:) drive went from ~900MB to ~100MB and then the error message was received.  So this is obviously the cause.

My question is this:

1. Does anyone know which default directory is used to store the temp files created while TortoiseHg/Mercurial bundles files in prep for a push?  This seems to be independent of the drive TortoiseHg is installed to.  I re-installed to a data drive with plenty of space and still used (C:) to store whatever temp files it was using.
2. Is there a way to configure TortoiseHg/Mercurial to use a temp directory of your choice?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The best solution is to clear up some other stuff. Like %TEMP%, old system temporary stuff that's not needed, etc. CCleaner can help there. You will often be able to save several gigabytes that way.

Comment: @ Chris Morgan:  Clearing up additional space on the drive is the overall solution.  However, we are using TortoiseHg / Mercurial as client solution and have little control over their environment.  Since the local repo was on their data drive (E:) with 300 GB free I was surprised to see the (C:) being used.  My main concern is  finding out specifics (if possible) to questions 1 & 2 as if we decide to use TortoiseHg / Mercurial on more widespread basis as a client/services solution we will have to provide some level of support...and having this type of knowledge will help us in that aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial is python and python has good platform specific defaults for temporary file locations.  They're pretty easily overridden if you want something other than the defaults, which on Windows are probably c:\temp.

http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir says it's:

1. The directory named by the TMPDIR environment variable.
2. The directory named by the TEMP environment variable.
3. The directory named by the TMP environment variable.
4. A platform-specific location:

   - On RiscOS, the directory named by the Wimp$ScrapDir environment variable.
   - On Windows, the directories C:\TEMP, C:\TMP, \TEMP, and \TMP, in that order.
   - On all other platforms, the directories /tmp, /var/tmp, and /usr/tmp, in that order.
5. As a last resort, the current working directory.

So if you've got software using Mercurial on a client computer set the environment variable to some place you know has space.

Comment: Actually, the default is `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp` or `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp` (approximate values, they may not be precisely correct, I can't be bothered looking up the right values.) The lookup order is also interesting because Windows' own lookup order in shell32.dll is TMP followed by TEMP. As well as putting TMPDIR higher, it reorders TEMP and TMP...

Comment: @Ry4an:  Based on the info it does seem like that is how the temp dir is determined.  Sounds like these variables are set in the 'tempfile.py' file.  Based on the Tortoisehg FAQ (http://goo.gl/8zaKT) it sates the following:  "TortoiseHg includes an entire Python distribution bundled up as DLLs. The standard library modules are all in the library.zip file in C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg." Unfortunately the library files are compiled (tempfile.pyo).  So we would not be able to easily configure the default python temp dir.  Based on my questions the info you provided answered my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Mercurial always stores internal files inside the ".hg" folder in the local repository folder.
Maybe TortoiseHg has a additional temp folder... don't know. Anyway you should try to push the files using the Mercurital command line client:

```
hg push
```

More information about the command line client you can find here [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/)

Another temporary solution might be the move these files via a file system simlink to another drive with more space left.

Comment: "file system symlink"? This is Windows we're talking about. Windows doesn't have such cool features. (On NTFS junctions are about the best you get which work consistently and they're tied to being in the same volume.)

Comment: And the GUI does exactly the same thing as `hg push`... it won't change a thing.

Comment: This is not the issue the OP is referring to.  The specific error is a result of running out of space on the system drive.