# TortoiseHg 'No space left on device' error while commiting to NAS device

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension

I have a number of large files about 5GB each, they are all on a remote NAS device. I want to commit them, so I created a repo on the NAS device, where the my files are, that went well, I made sure TortoiseHg had large files extension ticked, and I then committed the files, this took a while, fair enough as I have over 100GB of these 5GB files to commit, after a long while, I got the error "No space left of device". The whole commit was rolled back.

I know that my desktop doesn't have 100+GB of free space, but that's why all the files are on the remote NAS, and why I'm using the large files extension. I don't want the footprint of the commit on my local machine, just need them to be committed on the remote NAS device.

Can anyone suggest what I have done wrong and a potential remedy.

I've got TortoiseHg 4.9.1

I forgot to say that most (not all) the files are files that have a .zip extension, basically large files that have been zipped up to create the 5GB files. I want to track these zipped files. I don't know if that is the problem

Comment: Does your NAS have an additional 100GB free, at least?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, Yes it has 2TB of free space left

Comment: Maybe unlikely to be the cause, but THG 4.9 is about 2 years old, you might want to update to 5.7 and just see if that makes any difference. In any event I wouldn't stick to the older version unless there is a specific reason.

Comment: would the fact that most of the files are zip files, i.e. 5GB zip files that I want to commit, does mercurial not like zip files?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566343/tortoisehg-no-space-left-on-device-error-while-pushing ?